# Checking if a string is palindromic repeatedly

Tags: arrays, string, palindrome

So checking if a string is a palindrome is trivial to do in linear time. However, let's say we are iterating from left to right on a string, and at each iteration, I want to check if string[start:curr] (everything from the beginning of the string to the current index, inclusive) is a palindrome. This will be n^2 as i have to do the linear palindrome checking repeatedly. Is there an optimization to do this?

Comment: What is the output of your function? Are you trying to determine whether your string contains a substring that is a palindrome, and return true or false accordingly?

Comment: The algorithm should check a string for all palindromic substrings in linear time. It shouldn't exit on the first found. However, i did a bit more research and it seems like Manacher's algorithm is meant for this. will have to try it out at some point